# Buildroot: Build only one package as both shared and static lib, all others shared only

Tags: c++, c, shared-libraries, static-libraries, buildroot

buildroot offers to possibility to build

- only static,
- only shared,
- or both shared and static libs

of the selected packages.

The assigned configuration elements are `BR2_STATIC_LIBS`, `BR2_STATIC_LIBS`, and `BR2_SHARED_STATIC_LIBS`.

### Question:

Is it possible to build both a shared and static lib for *one package only*, while building only shared libs for *all the other packages*?

The one project which I want a static lib of would be an autotools-based package.

### My effort:

I did read the manual, but to no avail. I did come up with one idea though, but I think it won't work: I could have buildroot call the `configure` script with some arguments defined by me forcing the additional creation of a static lib. However, this would collide with the arguments buildroot is providing, which are forcing `configure` to do quite the opposite. (Create shared lib only.)

Thank you!

Unfortunately I can't even tell which version of buildroot I am using, as I did not find a way to get buildroots version number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buildroot does not directly support changing options for one package only. That would simply explode the number of options.

The easiest way to do this is to edit `package/foo/foo.mk` and add the following line to it:

```
FOO_CONF_OPTS += --enable-static
```

These options come after the default autoconfig options (which contain `--enable-shared --disable-static`) and will thus override them.

If you don't want to touch the Buildroot sources, you can also do this in your `local.mk` or in a `BR2_EXTERNAL` -- see the manual for how to set these up.

The Buildroot version number is encoded at the top of the Makefile (line 90 in current master) in the variable `BR2_VERSION`. You can also look at the top of the generated `.config` file, which contains the version extended with the git commit hash.

Comment: Defining `FOO_CONF_OPTS` was what I had in mind as well. However, I did not know that subsequent options override preceding ones. This makes it a solution indeed!

Comment: Note that most, but not all Buildroot supported packages are autoconf packages, and that most but not all autoconf packages support the "--enable-static" option. So YMMV regarding "--enable-static". You need to look carefully at the individual package's build system.